# Need to retrieve additional values based on Name key in table from DB within VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, oledb

So initially I retrieved all values with the name identifier within a table I have, and placed them into a combo box. The data that was loaded into the table is:

```vb
EstablishConnection("SELECT Name FROM Publishers")
```

I used the Query builder within the table adapter configuration wizard to create a string inquiry

```sql
SELECT        PubID, [Company Name], Address, City, State, Zip, Telephone, Fax
FROM          Publishers
WHERE         Name=''
```

And in VB implemented it with the selected value of the combobox

```vb
EstablishConnection(String.Format("SELECT PubID, [Company Name], Address, City, State, Zip, Telephone, Fax FROM Publishers WHERE Name='{0}'", oleDbCmbNames.SelectedItem.ToString()))
```

But, it only returns one value, and not all and says that the DB is missing based on the exception that I gave it.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub PublishersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.PublishersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ContactsDataSet)

    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ContactsDataSet.Publishers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.PublishersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ContactsDataSet.Publishers)

        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ContactsDataSet.Publishers' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.PublishersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ContactsDataSet.Publishers)

        'Establish a connection to the DB and fill combobox with names
        EstablishConnection("SELECT Name FROM Publishers")

    End Sub

    ' Instantiate Connection
    Dim connection As OleDb.OleDbConnection

    ' This function prepares, establishs, inquires, and closes the connection to the DB
    Public Sub EstablishConnection(request As String)

        Try
            ' Initialize new connection
            connection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection

            ' Initialize SQL inquiry
            Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand()

            ' Assign Inquiry request to command
            command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(request, connection)

            ' Assign db source before establishing a connection
            connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Contacts.mdb"

            ' Open connection
            connection.Open()

            ' Initialize DB reader with inquiry
            Dim oleDBReader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

            If oleDbCmbNames.Items.Count = 0 Then
                ' Read db, return inquries
                While oleDBReader.Read
                    ' Add each inquiry name string to combobox
                    oleDbCmbNames.Items.Add(oleDBReader("Name").ToString)
                End While
            ElseIf oleDbCmbNames.Items.Count > 0 Then
                ' Read db, return inquries
                While oleDBReader.Read()
                    PubIDLabelTextResult.Text = oleDBReader.Item("PubID").ToString
                    Company_NameLabelTextResult.Text = oleDBReader.Item("[Company Name]").ToString
                    AddressLabelTextResult.Text = oleDBReader.Item("Address").ToString
                    CityLabelTextResult.Text = oleDBReader.Item("City").ToString
                    StateLabelTextResult.Text = oleDBReader.Item("State").ToString
                    ZipLabelTextResult.Text = oleDBReader.Item("Zip").ToString
                    TelephoneLabelTextResult.Text = oleDBReader.Item("Telephone").ToString
                    FaxLabelTextResult.Text = oleDBReader.Item("Fax").ToString
                End While
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Return if db not found or cannot connect.
            MessageBox.Show("Could not connect to DB. Ensure DB is not missing.")
        Finally
            ' Close connection
            connection.Close()
        End Try



    End Sub

    Private Sub oleDbCmbNames_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles oleDbCmbNames.SelectedIndexChanged
        EstablishConnection(String.Format("SELECT PubID, [Company Name], Address, City, State, Zip, Telephone, Fax FROM Publishers WHERE Name='{0}'", oleDbCmbNames.SelectedItem.ToString().Trim))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Noo.. it was going so right (using tableadapters) and then went so wrong (started using data adapters and sql injection hacking prone techniques).. easy fix though, just gotta throw away the bad code and give a quick lesson on how it’s supposed to be

Comment: But first a question. Is it your intent that a combo box is loaded with publisher names, and changing the combo causes all the other data on the form to change (I.e. the combo is used as a navigator for multiple publisher records) or is it intended to be that the combo chooses which publisher to assign to something else, say an author? Do you have text boxes full of author details and a combo to choose which publisher to assign to them?

Comment: That is correct, that is the intent. Once the Pub name is selected in the combo box, the label.text field are then populated with the respected data.

Comment: Cool. Well, you already downloaded all the data you need so follow the instructions in the answer I posted for guidance how to link your already downloaded data up so the combo chooses it

Comment: Cool, I ty for that. Unfortunately, I am currently at work on a 13 hour shift, I will try when I get home tonight and will let you know how it went

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for the question I asked in the comments I’m making the assumption that you want to use the combo box as a navigation device.. you change the combo and a bunch of other controls on the form alter their contents. I’m assuming this from what it looks like the code is trying to do. If it’s not what you’re trying to do let me know and I’ll make a revised answer

So you’ve got a dataset and a tableadapter that loads all your publishers. Twice, actually - you can remove one of those identical fill commands from the form Load event handler. No point having two calls to the same thing right after each other

Next, you need to throw all that code in EstablishConnection away, and every call to it. Using data adapters and tableadapters together, particularly when you’re just starting out, will lead to confusion. Tableadapters are great, they generate safe sql that can have parameters in and are easy to use. What you have here in your EstablishConnection sub is a very unsafe way of running SQL.. For why, take a read of http://bobby-tables.com then come back and delete that code so you just have this:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub PublishersBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.PublishersBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.ContactsDataSet)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.PublishersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ContactsDataSet.Publishers)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Yep, that all the code your form code behind needs to contain at the moment

Now, go to your form designer and delete all the combos, text boxes, labels etc that relate to a publisher. I know it sounds like I’m trying to get you to trash your project but this is so I can get to a consistent state where we’re on the same page and I know what’s on your form and how it is wired up.

After you cleared your form (you can leave the ContactsDataSet, PublisherTableAdapter and other things down the bottom, plus any controls not related to publishers) open the View menu, go to Other Windows and pick Data Sources. It’ll show a tool panel like this (and this is a great pic because it demos some other points too):

[image]
([credit](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17456/Access-image-metadata-using-Visual-Studio-s-new-ob)))

Because, from the code above, it seems to me that you want to load your publisher details into labels instead of text boxes you can expand your contacts dataset, expand the publishers node and change the type of the nodes under it (the address, zip, phone, fax etc) from text box to label. After you changed them to label drag and drop them one by one onto the form. Alternatively, change the header node from DatagridView to Details and then drag the header node onto the form to quickly create a label for each of everything under the header node

You now have a bunch of labels that are data bound (connected) to your contacts dataset publishers table. You can click any label and look in the (Data Bindings) line of the properties grid and see their Text property is connected to a column of the publishers table, and their data source is something called a publishersBindingSource. The binding source maintains the concept of “current record” in a list of multiple records. You have 100 publishers, you set the bindingsource’s current record to the 50th, all the labels show the data for the 50th publisher. You tell the bindingsource to move to the 51st publisher and all the labels change their content automatically. You can see this in action by running your project, and clicking the arrows in the bindingnavigator at the top of the form. The call to Fill in the form load loaded 100 publishers (say), the bindingsource starts pointing to the first one, clicking next/prev/last or typing a number in will change the current record of the bindingsource that sits between the list of 100 publishers in the dataset, and your controls (which can only show one publisher at once)

Now, we add a combo to the form to act as a navigator:

- add a combo to your form
- in the properties window set its data source to be the *PublishersBindingSource* - this is vital
- type the word *Name* into the DisplayMember setting - necessary to get the combo to show the right thing
- set the DropDownStyle to be DropDownList - optional but an editable combo is really confusing in this context

Run your project

When configured like this, a combo will show the list of items it finds in the bindingsource, and the currently selected one will drive the bindingsource’s current record. Changing the selected item in the combo will cause all the labels to change because the combo influenced the bindingsource’s current record. The combo doesn’t need anything else to act as a navigator, and indeed trying to bind something else will cause it to start acting like an editor of the data in the current record, not a navigator of all records

Comment: Ty kindly. The book we are using doesn't go into much detail about working with databases. The teacher threw in the assignment knowing most of the students wouldn't understand (including me), but I had background in foundational programming and knew where to look (outside of stack). It sucks we're all going to likely get a piss poor grade for something that wasn't covered in the book, but you came through and I thank you for that. Very much appreciated.

Comment: It would be interesting for you to post the assignment as an edit to the question. I’d like to read it and see if I can spot anything that indicates it is expected to be done a particular way - chiefly concerned that the supervisor won’t know about datasets, tableadapters and databinding and that this (correct) way of dog thinks will seem like voodoo magic compared to the usual crappy way that educational institutions seem to teach their students how to do DB access (we see a lot of people doing DB assignments and the code they’ve apparently been taught is really terrible, primitive stuff)

Comment: This is the only [page](https://prnt.sc/s239gm) from the book explaining how to set up oledb, after this page, there is nothing. This is the [assignment](https://prnt.sc/s239zo) we were given. This doesn't really explain much, only instructions we were given was "do it"

Comment: That's horrendous, especially the part where the book says that Dispose "closes the connection for the datatable"

Comment: The one thing the assignment mentions that I didn't cover or make a recommendation on is sorting the list of publishers. Because the publisher combo is bound through a bindingsource you can get the bindingSource to do the sort. Set the `publishersBindingSource.Sort = "[Name] ASC"` where Name is the name of the column that holds the publisher name. The square brackets are recommended/required - they indicate to the bindingSource that it is the column. If you were sorting on Age descending the syntax would be `[Age] DESC"`

Comment: I think it would be worth speaking with your supervisor before submitting anything, to find out how this could be marked. say you've done it using tableadapters, datasets and databinding but appreciate that this is a slightly different technique than the only fragment of data access in the course book. You're concerned that if there is a specific form to the deliverable assignment, such as "it must demonstrate direct use of a dataadapter with a non parameterized and a parameterized query pair to fill all publishers, and then details for a specific publisher upon change of a combo box" or is..

Comment: ..the design and implementation  of the task completely the student's choice and the only assessment is of the resulting GUI that it matches and behaves as the spec says?